# How to visualize data in paraview with fortran

Tags: fortran, visualization, paraview

I wrote a program in Fortran which calculates molecular movements (basically their centers in 3d space - xyz). I'd like to visualize these data in ParaView, which I'm capable of. My programs output is VTK file which I can load into ParaView and see everything I need clearly. But I'd like to somehow make this process autonomous.

Basically I'd like to do computations and after some steps I'd like to visualize molecules with ParaaView, take a screenshot from certain angle save images as `png` (or any other `img` format which ParaView supports). Because of a high number of iterations I can't do this myself, therefore I thought about incorporating some kind of script into my Fortran code or any other way to make this happen, but I don't even know if this is possible or how?

I do really hope you can help me I'm in a pinch here, I'm quite new to Fortran, so I hope what I'm asking for is not impossible.

I'd like to thank you very much for any help you can provide me with. (I'm not asking for a prepared script, but for some hint/guide how to do this if possible, but I'm not against examples either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kyle Kanos said, you can script Paraview using Python. Those scripts then can be called from Fortran using `call SYSTEM('cmd',status)` (pre-Fortran 2008, non-standard, but supported by at least `gfortran` and `ifort`) or `call EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE('cmd')` (Fortran 2008).

Here is the GCC documentation: [`SYSTEM`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM.html) and [`EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html#EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE).

Comment: Note that if you want to use the *subroutine* `SYSTEM`, you need to add an integer `status` after the `'cmd'` (i.e. `CALL SYSTEM('cmd', status)`); the *function* `SYSTEM` takes no such argument (e.g., `status = SYSTEM('cmd')`).

Comment: You do not need to add `status` in `SYSTEM`, it is optional.

Comment: Thank you very much, all of you (including Kyle Kanos) really helped me. I was able to make my program with all the stuff needed thanks to you guys!

Comment: @VicoLemp Welcome to SO! Since you are new, you might want to check [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

Paraview has [Python built](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python_Scripting) into it for this exact purpose.